# How to transfer marker popup to sidebar?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm creatting web app with React Leaflet. How I can transfer marker popup to react-leaflet-sideatabs

Local machine with react (windows 10)

```
 <Sidebar
          id="sidebar"
          position="right"
          collapsed={this.state.collapsed}
          closeIcon={<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleRight} />}
          selected={this.state.selected}
          onOpen={this.onOpen.bind(this)}
          onClose={this.onClose.bind(this)}
 >
     <Tab
            id="markerinfo"
            header="Information"
            icon={<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfoCircle} />}
          >
            // I need to transfer marker information here
     </Tab>
</Sidebar>
```

Comment: Marker declaring this way

<Marker position={[53.5098, 49.4191]} icon={parkIc}>
      <Popup>Central park</Popup>
 </Marker>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question. But I think the answer is simply React state. Say you have a marker and only the title is kept in state, you can take it anywhere for that matter.

See this sandbox example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sidebar-marker-wknsp

Note: the [example](https://github.com/eferhatg/react-leaflet-sidetabs) from that sidebar GitHub page was not working with my styling/etc on code sandbox.io so slightly adapted.